# Automatic human readable time interval

Tags: java, api, date, datetime, time

I would like to express some **time intervals** in a human readable format. I was looking for a library automatically able to choose the correct size of the units. The intervals will range from milliseconds to weeks. Something like

- 0.2s
- 2:00
- 4 days
- ...

I know I could manually check the size of the argument and then convert it but before reinventing the wheel I wanted to ask if there is a (standard) library to achieve that.

- [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) does the conversions but there is no knowledge about the size of the argument
- a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_duration.html) represents exactly what I need but I did not find much about representation (but for the ISO8601 formatting of [ReadableDuration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableDuration.html))

**Edit**:

My input in in nanoseconds and output as described above.

Comment: Give some sample inputs and outputs of what you want?

Comment: @djaqeel I edited the question: input in nanoseconds (or milliseconds) and output as human readable as possible

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)

> PrettyTime is an OpenSource time formatting library. Completely customizable, PrettyTime creates human readable, relative timestamps like those seen on Digg, Twitter, and Facebook. It’s simple, get started “right now!” and in over 18 languages!

**For Example**

```
    PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
    System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
    //prints: “right now”

    PrettyTime t = new PrettyTime(new Date(3155692597470L * 3L));
    t.format(new Date(0));
    //3 centuries ago
```