# Displaying relative date in JSTL

Tags: jsp, date, datetime, jstl

Until now, I have displayed dates with `<fmt:formatDate ... />`. However, now I need to display dates relative to the current date. So, I have a `java.util.Date` object, and I want to display when that date was, e.g. "Today, 12:34 PM", "Yesterday, 12:34 PM", "7 days ago" or similar. So relative to the current time.

How would I go about this? Is there any existing taglib that I can use, or do I have to write my own JSTL tag? It's no problem to do so, but I just don't want to invent something if it already exists. Or maybe there is another/better way?

A bonus question: should I be computing this stuff before handing off my model to the view (i.e. in plain Java), or is it okay to do this stuff in the view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any relevant taglib available for that but you could create one wrapping [`PrettyTime`](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)

---

- [Automatic human readable time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521967/automatic-human-readable-time-interval)